# How to make the arrow head still look nice for a short curved path?

Tags: pstricks

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node,multido}
\psset{arcangle=90,nodesep=3pt,arrows=->}
\begin{document}
\multido{\n=3+-.75}{4}{%
\pspicture(3,3)
\rput[bl](0,1){\rnode[t]{A}{A}}
\rput[br](\n,1){\rnode[t]{B}{B}}
\ncarc{A}{B}
\endpspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Using a Computer Modern style arrow could help.

Comment: change the `arcangle` for each iteration. Don't arrive at the second node 90 degrees always.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just for fun, with TikZ and the new CVS `bending` library:

```
\documentclass[border=0.125cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,bending}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\tikzset{>=Stealth}
\node at (0.5,1) {Normal};
\node (A) {A};
\node (B) at (1 ,0) {B};
\draw [<->] (A.north) .. controls ++(0,0.25) and ++(0,0.25) .. (B.north);

\tikzset{xshift=2cm, >={Stealth[bend]}}
\node at (0.5,1) {Bent};
\node (A) {A};
\node (B) at (1 ,0) {B};
\draw [<->] (A.north) .. controls ++(0,0.25) and ++(0,0.25) .. (B.north);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: that is not the same, your start and end angles are _not_ 90 degrees

Comment: @Herbert the start and end angles for the path are now 90 degrees. The adjustments to the path and arrow tip angle are computed by the library.

Comment: I see, you are right